# CSS: Showing an unsorted list in a tile-like style

Tags: css

I have an unsorted list which I want do display in a tile-like style using CSS.
This is my list:

```
<ul>
  <li>Area 1</li>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Topic 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Topic 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Topic 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Topic 4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <li>Area 2</li>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Topic 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Topic 6</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

This is the needed Output:
Unfortunately I cannot post images here (due to my low reputation).

```
+---------------------------+
|            Area 1         |
+---------------------------+

+-------+ +-------+ +-------+
|Topic 1| |Topic 2| |Topic 3|
+-------+ +-------+ +-------+
+-------+ 
|Topic 4| 
+-------+ 


+---------------------------+
|            Area 2         |
+---------------------------+

+-------+ +-------+
|Topic 5| |Topic 6|
+-------+ +-------+
```

[image]

In a first step it would be enough if the list is only these 2 steps deep.

I checked several approaches using CSS, but failed.
Can someone help me please with the solution or an approach?

Best regards,
Stefan

Comment: Where did you get stuck, I realise that my 'knowing CSS' biases my opinion slightly, but this looks relatively easy (using `width` and `display`, or `float`, appropriately). Where did your attempts fail? Can you show us your attempt(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[- LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/UwOlexo/2/edit)**
**[- RESPONSIVE](http://jsbin.com/UwOlexo/4/edit)**

[image]

Corrected HTML:

```
<ul>

  <li><span>Area 1</span>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Topic 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Topic 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Topic 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Topic 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><span>Area 2</span>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Topic 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Topic 6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
  width:300px;
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
  overflow:auto;
}
ul > li{
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
li span{
  display:block;
  clear:both;
  background:#5A9BD5;
  padding:15px 0;
}
ul ul li{
  float:left;
  width:90px;
  margin:15px 15px 0 0;
}
ul ul li:nth-child(3){
  margin-right:0;
}
ul li a{
  background:#5A9BD5;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  padding:15px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few approaches you could take. One is to use floats, like so:

```
ul li {
    clear: left;
}
ul li ul li { 
    clear: none;
    float: left; 
    width: 33.33%; 
}
```

Another is display: inline-block. But note you'd need to remove any whitespace and line breaks from between the list items (in the HTML):

```
ul li li { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.33%; 
}
```

Note IE7 doesn't do inline-block. To make it work there (if necessary) add this:

.ie7 ul li li {
        display: inline;
        zoom: 1;
   }

(I use conditional commments to add the .ie7 class to the HTML element)

Answer (score 1):

First thing. You cannot have a `<ul>` directly under a parent `<ul>`.

```
<ul>
  <li>Area 1</li>
  <!-- this is wrong -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Topic 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Topic 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Topic 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Topic 4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <li>Area 2</li>
  <!-- this is wrong -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Topic 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Topic 6</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

---

So you can change the markup this way:

```
<ul>
  <li>Area 1</li>
  <li class="tiles">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Topic 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Topic 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Topic 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Topic 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Area 2</li>
  <li class="tiles">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Topic 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Topic 6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now the CSS:

```css
ul, li {display: block; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
ul {background: #fff;}
li {line-height: 50px; width: 100%; text-align: center; background: #66f; margin: 5px;}
li.tiles ul li {width: 33%; float: left; margin: 5px 0; background: none;}
li.tiles ul {overflow: hidden;}
li.tiles {text-align: left; margin: 0;}
a {color: #fff; text-decoration: none; display: block; background: #66f; margin: 5px;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/LjCHW/1/

---

Without the use of `class` attribute.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>Area 1</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Topic 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Topic 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Topic 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Topic 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Area 2</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Topic 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Topic 6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```css
ul, li {display: block; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
ul {background: #fff;}
li {line-height: 50px; width: 100%; text-align: center; background: #66f; margin: 5px;}
li ul li {width: 33%; float: left; margin: 5px 0; background: none;}
li ul {overflow: hidden;}
a {color: #fff; text-decoration: none; display: block; background: #66f; margin: 5px;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/LjCHW/2/

Comment: Thank you for your answer - the code works as I need it. My further problem is that you use a class. I receive the unsorted list in a fixed form - the wrong <ul>-structure can be fixed there, but unfortunalety not the class-attribute. Is it possible to use your css sniplet without any class definition?  Interesting: the html-code comes out of a Microsoft-Standard-Menu-Control - so far with Microsoft and the standards :)

Comment: @StefanMeyer Yes, possible. I will update the answer without using class. Give me a moment.

Comment: @StefanMeyer Updated without using classes.

Comment: THIS is a perfect base for my further investigations! Thank you Praveen, it works.